# How to add a react element into the DOM node (only on the user-interaction like on click) without using the state?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, react

I'm working on a WP plugin project that requires a react element to take the position of the main DOM node(main component) content when the button is clicked, but without the use of state in the main component as I don't want to re-render that component.

Comment: I don't really understand your concern about state. Do you have code that shows what you're trying to do? Also, this sounds like a React-specific issue, rather than anything to do with WordPress.